# How to find probability from a sequence of numbers, which is being divided into two equal parts?

Tags: probability

There is a sequence of numbers $1,2,\ldots,4N$, which is being divided into two equal parts. I need to find probability, that in every part there will be equal count of even and odd numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume these are labelled parts, left box, right box. The number of ways to choose the occupants of the left box is $\binom{4N}{2N}$. These are all **equally likely**.

Now we count the **favourables**, the ways in which the left box has equal numbers of evens and odds. There are $\binom{2N}{N}$ ways to choose the evens, and for each way there are $\binom{2N}{N}$ ways to choose the odds, for a total of $\binom{2N}{N}^2$.

For the probability, divide.